# UITableView has unwanted animation when reloadData is called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView, if I scroll the content a little and then call `reloadData` the table appears to do a scrolling animation when the data is reloaded.

[image]

table setup called in `viewDidLoad`:

```
func setupTableView() {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "AnswerCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "AnswerCell")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuizDescription", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "QuizDescription")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuestionNumberCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "QuestionNumberCell")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 135
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
```

When the submit button is pressed `tableView.reloadData()` is called. Any ideas why this animation is happening? What can I do to stop it?

Comment: Have you solved? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset position first, before calling `reloadData`.

```
 tableView.contentOffset = .zero
```

Comment: Tried this. Still animates though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reload of tableview in [performWithoutAnimation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622484-performwithoutanimation?language=objc) block:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```