# Unwanted UITableView reload animation when navigating from iOS 11 search controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, ios11

I have a view controller with a tableview containing a list of chats, a search controller enbeded in the navigation item (iOS 11 feature)

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
definesPresentationContext = true
```

When the user taps a chat in the table view the app pushes a new view controller with another table view containing messages for that chat. That works like it is supposed to:

[image]

The problem is that when the user activates the search controller, find some chat and taps it, the pushed view controller containing table view with the chat messages does some really strange **animation with the table view that should not happen**:

[image]

I load the data before the actual navigation and bind it to the table view in `viewDidLoad` using just `reload()` on the table view. The problematic table view uses auto layout and custom cells.

The problem is very similar to [UITableView has unwanted animation when reloadData is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881543/uitableview-has-unwanted-animation-when-reloaddata-is-called) but for me it only happens when the iOS 11 search controller is active.

**Edit**: If I remove `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and use a fixed height using `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` the problem is still there

Comment: I am not sure but would it help if you reload tableview inside performWithoutAnimation block.

        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

Comment: I tried that, did not help. reloadData() is called in viewDidLoad so I think the tableview is loaded before the VC is displayed so the animation is not related to reload.

Comment: This looks like your view controller is performing a layout pass during the push animation. I'd suggest making sure your view and all its subviews are laid out in its final state before the view controller is being presented.

Comment: Are you doing the auto-layout in Interface builder or by code? can you post an excerpt from your auto-layout code/logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would simply hide the searchView controller before presenting the new view controller. 
( Using UIView.animates with a completion handler for example )

I would not try to investigate further because since iOS11, there is an esoteric problem in the safe area management. A bug ? :)

Even the launch screens layouts are not correctly handled. 
So many majors logos miss their middle part at launch !

Comment: I tried that, hiding the search before navigating to the chat detail. It is slow for the user and it is not that easy to make it active and focused, with keyboard displayed navigating back to the chats screen.

Comment: And the reverse ? Show the navigation bar before presenting the detail controller ( without delay - at the same time ).

Comment: In a recent project, I have embedded a search field in the navigation bar. It would probably solve this animation problem. However, I agree it changes your interface. I'm going to far ;) Cheers and good luck.

Comment: I did not really find a solution, but your suggestion of just deactivating the search before the navigation and activating it again when back is the best was the best way to go, so the bounty goes to you

Answer (score 4):

If you just hide the searchBar before pushing a new viewController then it may fix your problem.

You need to create a global variable for searchBarCancelButton and find the cancel button from its subviews when you search something

```
let buttons = searchController.searchBar.subviews.first?.subviews.filter { (view) -> Bool in
            return NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder) == "UINavigationButton"
        } as? [UIButton]
        searchBarCancelButton = buttons?.first
```

then you can manually cancel it.

```
self.searchBarCancelButton?.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` right after dequeuing and setting a content of the cell

Comment: No idea what that would help but I tried it and it did not.

Comment: It could help because it animates the difference between frame.height after it dequeuing a cell and laying out cells subviews. If you, for example, set explicit cell height it will stop animate the cel height

Comment: If I set cell height using `heightForRowAt` the problem is still there, still seeing the unwanted animation

Comment: You can check very small test project with very similar functionality in my repo https://github.com/blob8129/Search. I wasn't able to reproduce unwanted animation effect. Maybe you would be able to spot the difference.

Comment: Youn can also try to configure your cell inside  UIView.performWithoutAnimation { } block.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11 completely revamped the safe area API, including scroll view inset adjustment behaviors, which can cause unwanted animation when ignored. Therefore, disable automatic content inset adjustment for the scroll view with the unwanted animation:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    // < iOS 11 logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not invoke `reloadData()` method in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. Instead of this reload your tableView with empty data in `viewDidLoad` so your `tableView` will show nothing and then in your `viewDidAppear` invoke `reloadData()` method to load all of your chats. This will restrict your tableView from loading with unwanted animation.

```
var shouldShowEmpty = true

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    shouldShowEmpty = false
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if shouldShowEmpty {
            return 0
        }
        return yourArray.count
    }
```

Comment: This will cause the data to appear "too late", visible to the user

Comment: You should manually trigger the cancel button of searchController. Because its dismissing the navigationBar so only resigningFirstResponder will not be enough.

Comment: I tried that, hiding the search before navigating to the chat detail. It is slow for the user and it is not that easy to make it active and focused, with keyboard displayed navigating back to the chats screen.

Comment: write `self.layoutIfNeeded()` in your Cell Class's `awakeFromNib` method if your using nib for cells.

Answer (score 0):

As per attachment, It looks like due to auto layout, cell's element's height was zero (`UILabel or UIImageView`) and then suddenly when table view reloads it gets the data inside the cell which increase its height(automatic dimension or whatever) which cause this animation.

Try to push it without animation or try to set fix cell's element's height and width and check is it still showing this animation.

Did you check without invoking UISearchBar, If you select on any cell same animation is happening ?? or did you try to remove UISearchbar and select on the cell and check the animation part ?

Please share your code so we can see more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, and I believe that solution is the same. The keyboard is causing the problem, to be more correct, keyboardWillHideNotification trigger. You have text field at the bottom, that probably listens to notifications for keyboard show/hide, where layoutIfNeeded() is triggered if you animate bottom constraint so that your keyboard doesn't overlap your text field. So when you finish your search in the search text field, keyboardWillHideNotification gets triggered at an unwanted time. I solved my issue by calling:

```
resignFirstResponder()
```

for the text field that causes this event. In my case, that was after pressing the button, in your, I believe it's in didSelect tableView cell in the search table view.

If you are still active at this issue, please let me know if you manage to solve it. I broke my head trying to solve this issue, which apparently is so simple and straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

- In VC2 Try a delay function before reloading table

  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    tableView.reloadData
  }

or else

- In VC1 in `didSelect` **resign first responder** of search controller before pushing to VC2

or

- In VC1 in `didSelect` **resign first responder** of search controller and set a **delay** before pushing to VC2.

Comment: Using magic numbers is often a half-solution... Why 0.1, why not 0.2 or 0.05.. Completion handlers are much safer.

Comment: Yup, it’s a half solution, some times it may help right..!